# What are the advantages and disadvantages of storing the number of comments in an integer column vs. calculating it on the fly?

Tags: web-development, php, database-design

Let's take CodeReview page as an example. If you go [here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions), you will see the list of the questions with their vote numbers and comment numbers

Now, I am wondering if these numbers are calculated on the fly (e.g. count the total comments in db for this question), or is there an actual field in the `questions` table called `voteCount` and it's incremented by one whenever someone votes for this question?

Just another question. Both VoteCount and CommentCount are just integers, what about the user information that is displayed for each question?

Hope this is the correct place to ask this question.

Comment: boosis I edited out references to Zend Framework (post text & tag) because the question really has nothing to do with it. If it did, i.e. was an implementation specific question, it would probably be off topic here. Check out [Database Administrators SE](http://dba.stackexchange.com/), I think you'll find quite a few relevant posts there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It really depends on the traffic of the site, and you should probably don't bother yourself with such decisions unless:

1. You've identified an actual bottleneck
2. You've identified an actual bottleneck on a very similar scenario in the past

Premature optimization is the buzzword, and [Donald Knuth describes it](http://pplab.snu.ac.kr/courses/adv_pl05/papers/p261-knuth.pdf)<sup>1</sup> better than I could possibly:

> Programmers waste enormous amounts of time thinking about, or worrying about, the speed of noncritical parts of their programs, and these attempts at efficiency actually have a strong negative impact when debugging and maintenance are considered. We should forget about small efficiencies, say about 97% of the time: **premature optimization is the root of all evil**. Yet we should not pass up our opportunities in that critical 3%.

The simplest approach is to have a `vote` table, where you log all votes. Typical fields would be `voteID`, `voterID`, `questionID`, `voteTimestamp`, and you could calculate the totals on each request. But, that will probably become a performance issue very soon, especially with a high traffic site as StackOverflow<sup>2</sup>.

In that case, my approach would be to run a scheduled background process<sup>3</sup> that calculates totals and stores them in a different table (or the question table), and possibly even in a document storage database<sup>4</sup>. Or, even in a memory cache<sup>5</sup>, if it makes sense.

There are other ways to cache calculated totals, these are the simplest ones (I think).

As for the user information, they are expected to change less often, so you could probably get away with caching them, without any special database realm approach.

Generally speaking `reads` are quite faster than `writes` and in common low traffic scenarios you'd be just fine by just sensibly caching your views. There is no definitive approach, mix and match as you identify bottlenecks.

<sub><sup>1</sup> Warning! PDF link.

<sup>2</sup> We can't really isolate CodeReview, it's based on the common platform, if something is a bottleneck on StackOverflow, by default it is (or will be) on CodeReview.

<sup>3</sup> [Cron](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron) is your best friend!

<sup>4</sup> Assuming the core database is relational.

<sup>5</sup> [Memcached](http://memcached.org/) is your other best friend!</sub>

Comment: Thanks for the reply Zaphod, but I really think this is a very important decision to make during the initial development. As you know db queries are the most common bottleneck of all. Let's say if I decide to calculate the votes on the fly, it means if I display 10 posts per page it means 10 extra db query (assuming there is no caching at all). But if I keep the counters in the same table as the post, there won't be any extra query needed.

Comment: I think keeping the vote count/comment count (or any similar integer counters) in the same table as the post sounds better solution. But what if I need to display the user information for each post (i.e. authorname)? of course authorid will be in the posts table but to get the author name, I need to go back to db for each post (again, assume no caching)

Comment: Sorry, I didn't see the second part of your answer :) instead of cron job, would it be better to increase the VoteCounter field in the questions table whenever user up votes it? If cron job is used, again it needs to scan a huge table to calculate the counters

Comment: @boosis, you would need to still do both. By storing it on your Q table as well as storing the vote itself (which you need to do unless someone can voting as much as they want on each Q) you are denormalizing your database. That means edge cases can cause explicit votes not to match the stored counter, as well as infrastructure issues, etc. Because of this you will need a method to reconcile your information - much in the same way StackExchange sites have rep-recalcs.

Comment: `I really think this is a very important decision to make during the initial development.`  I know from experience that _generally_ it's not, but unless I have a very specific idea of what you're building I can't say if that applies to your situation. `instead of cron job, would it be better to increase the VoteCounter field in the questions table whenever user up votes it? If cron job is used, again it needs to scan a huge table to calculate the counters` It highly depends on what you are building. Define huge, how many millions of rows are you talking about?

Comment: @DanMcGrath, yes, all votes will be saved in a separate table for obvious reasons. Q table will only record the number of votes for the questions.

Comment: @ZaphodBeeblebrox Well there is nothing specific I am building. I am asking this question as I always come across this and always wondered how others do it. I am reading about Domain Driven Design and when I see term `object graph` this came to my mind :)

Comment: what I mean, when you retrieve a model from db, do you retrieve whole related models, although this is not our discussion here ;)

Comment: @boosis Keeping most relevant information in the same table is not a bad approach, if most of your reads are using them. If not, then you may unwittingly bloat the table with useless information. That's why you have to identify the bottleneck first, you can never be 100% certain. That said, it's not a bad approach to start with (and revise later, if there are performance issues).

Comment: @boosis `what I mean, when you retrieve a model from db ...` I didn't really understand what you mean there, could you clarify that a bit?

Comment: @ZaphodBeeblebrox, so **number** of votes are relevant to question and it's displayed whenever I display the question, so it should be in the questions table, right? If I want to display the actual votes, then I can query the `votes` table and get the votes.

Comment: @boosis Yes, that's a pretty standard approach, although you end up with repeated content (since it's pretty easy to calculate the total votes, you should think of them as existing content). But it's a pretty standard approach, something like database caching if you will.

Comment: @ZaphodBeeblebrox Let's say you want to show a `blog post`. Each blog post will have an `author`, will have multiple `tags`, will have multiple `comments` etc. So if you only want to display blog title and the total number of comments, there is no need to load all comments from db. Hope this is clearer.

Comment: @boosis Yeap, that's very close to the generic scenario I head in mind for database caching. Go for it!

Comment: @boosis No worries, I always enjoy on topic first time questions, it's quite refreshing. Do check out DBA SE, and ask specific database questions there, the crowd there is way more educated in the dark arts of database optimization than we are...